# When I executed my 1st selenium code I got this error- noClassDefFoundError

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just started learning selenium. Downloaded and configured the jars & drivers as demonstrated on the web.

code: java

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
}
```

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer
Caused by:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.Timer

-used tools-
Java - JDK 15
chrome - 89

In addition, is it necessary to use the external selenium server and standalone server(4.0 alpha)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Edit your question, paste the code, and properly format it instead. This includes the error message.

Comment: Even added netty. common.4.0 final jar file, still getting error.

Comment: I don't know what is the actual trick, removed all the jars and changed my JDK to 1.8 Eclipse is pretty comfortable than the IntelliJ for selenium.

No need to download and add the additional jar files independently. Selenium java, chrome driver is sufficient for the task. If required for higher projects better to use maven.

Answer (score 0):

Clear All the selenium jars from the project.
Add the selenium API jars first to external library(eclipse).
Then add the library folder jar files from selenium to external library(eclipse).
Now, run & see the output.

Comment: Is it necessary to use eclipse, as I'm using the IntelliJ idea for the java?